# Spouse was given a laptop system after organization was bought out. Is there a way to restore the default local policies on the Windows 10 system?

Tags: windows, group-policy, domain, local

As the title suggests. We were able to restore admin and the normal users logins. Thing I have complete:

- Restore secpol using secedit
- Restore services.msc
- Removed Registry entries relevant to policies
- Restore GPO using GPupdate /force /boot after removing from domain  -  -
- Assigned a normal workgroup

Everything is in a state of 'Not configured' but has not restored the state as normal OS user. At this point I am about to wipe out the OS, but wondering if there is anything left to resort to before wiping it out. Anything I do now like opening command prompt, task manager, or windows explorer requires elevated privileges still. Right+click was still disabled, but that has been fixed.

Comment: Just wipe it. Saves you a lot of hassle.

Comment: I'm not sure _how_ Explorer or Cmd could be configured to require elevation just to open – this sounds like some "manual" configuration has been done... but for Task Manager that's normal, it's what you get if UAC is set to the maximum level (one notch higher than default). Still, agree that you should just do the "factory reset" that Windows offers, and if that doesn't help then wipe and reinstall.

Comment: Windows and other updates might also come from company servers rather than Microsoft directly, which might not be possible anymore once it's out of the company domain.

Comment: Follow @Gantendo advice.  Reset the whole thing which is built into windows without a re-install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following describes how to reset Group Policy to default in Windows 10.

#### Method 1: Reset Group Policy Settings via Local Group Policy Editor

##### Open Group Editor

You can press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `gpedit.msc` in Run dialog, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open Local Group Policy Editor.

In Group Policy Editor window, you can click as following path: “Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> All Settings.”

Next, click State column in the right window, and it will display the policy settings by category. You can easily find the Enabled/Disabled policies at the top.

Then you can change the state of those policies from Enabled/Disabled to Not Configured.

Continue to find the following path in Group Policy Editor: “Local Computer Policy -> User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> All Settings.” And do the same to change the modified Group Policy settings from Enabled/Disabled to Not Configured.

##### Save the changes.

To make the resetting take effect, you can restart your computer, or open elevated Command Prompt, and type `gpupdate.exe /force`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command.

By default, all policies in Group Policy Editor are set to "Not Configured". By doing so, you can reset all Group Policy settings to default in Windows 10.

If you want reset specific modified Group Policy setting to default, you can find that policy in Group Policy Editor and do the same to reset individual policy setting to default.

#### Method 2: Reset Group Policy Settings to Default with Command Prompt.

If you don’t know which policies you have modified, you can also use Windows Command Prompt to reset all Group Policy settings to default.

By deleting the Group Policy settings folder from your computer hard drive, you can reset all the policies to default.

Click “Start,” type cmd, right-click Command Prompt app to choose Run as administrator.

Next, type the command: `RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy"`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Next, type this command: `RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To make the resetting take effect, you can restart your computer, or open elevated Command Prompt, and type `gpupdate.exe /force`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command.